# WinJS setInterval() hangs

Tags: javascript, multithreading, user-interface, winjs

I'm working on creating a custom UI cursor.  The cursor position is determined by checking some input values every 5ms and adjusting the style.top and style.left properties on a DOM element.  Usually this works very smoothly, however I find that the cursor sometimes hangs.  I'm not exactly sure what's causing this but it appears to be related to requests returning slowly in WinJS.xhr() calls.

Is there a better way to update my cursor UI that will keep it running smoothly?  Can I use another thread for this?

Answer (score 1):

Note that 5ms is too fast for screen refresh cycles. A 60Hz screen will refresh at 16.7ms intervals tops, so there's no reason to use shorter intervals. In this case, you want to use requestAnimationFrame rather than setInterval, because then you know that your UI work will be aligned to screen refreshes. Otherwise you'll certainly drop some frames in your cursor animation due to the misalignment.

Still, any blocking work on the UI thread will block your cursor refresh. WinJS.xhr is not necessarily the direct culprit here--it's basically a wrapper for XMLHttpRequest, which it itself an async call that works on another thread. *However,* the code that processes the results of that request--that is, whatever you have inside the completed handler for the promise returned from WinJS.xhr, *will* run on the UI thread. So if you're doing a bunch of work there, you'll probably block a few refresh cycles

Unfortuantely, JavaScript doesn't give you direct access to creating separate threads. WinJS. however, does provide a scheduler mechanism for this purpose. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301978.aspx and also http://try.buildwinjs.com/default.aspx#scheduler. I also wrote a post on the Windows dev blog: [Managing the JavaScript UI thread with the WinJS Scheduler](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2014/03/04/managing-the-javascript-ui-thread-with-the-winjs-scheduler.aspx).

What you'll do here is run your animation code with high priority and run your WinJS.xhr completed handler at a normal or lower priority.